# Data not getting displayed in jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid to display,sort and filter records. At the moment, I have go the js code working, but I think there is something wrong with my controller code, that is not populating the grid. I can see only an empty blak jqgrid with the message "No records to display". Please let me know whats going wrong.
Here is my code:
Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pagesize = rows;
        var custList = db.Customers.Select(
                                    c => new
                                    {
                                        c.ID,
                                        c.Company,
                                        c.FirstName,
                                        c.EMail,
                                        c.Status
                                    });
        int totalCustomers = custList.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalCustomers / (float)rows);
        if(sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
        {
            custList = custList.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
            custList = custList.Skip(pageIndex * pagesize).Take(pagesize);
        }
        else
        {
            custList = custList.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
            custList = custList.Skip(pageIndex * pagesize).Take(pagesize);
        }
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            customers = totalCustomers,
            rows = custList
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. Dint know I would get the solution so quickly. I removed all the existing code from the controller and just added this:

```
 public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var customers = db.Customers.Select(m => new { ID = m.ID, Company = m.Company, FirstName = m.FirstName, Email = m.EMail, Status = m.Status }).ToList();
        return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is all it needs,just two lines of code, rest of the functionalities, ie paging, sorting, filtering is already provided by jqwidgets:) Hope this helps someone who was facing a similar problem as mine.
The script is as follows:

```
 var source =
        {
            //localdata: GetData(),
            url: '/Client/GetData',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            datafields: [
                { name: 'ID', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'Company' },
                { name: 'FirstName' },
                { name: 'EMail' },
                { name: 'Status' }
            ]

        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        // initialize jqxGrid
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            source: dataAdapter,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                    { text: 'Client Id', datafield: 'ID', width: 200 },
                    { text: 'Company', datafield: 'Company', width: 200 },
                    { text: 'Username', datafield: 'FirstName', width: 180 },
                    { text: 'Email', datafield: 'EMail', width: 100 },
                    { text: 'Status', datafield: 'Status', width: 140 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: you use wrong tag for the question: "jqgrid" instead of "jqxgrid".